# Rails Access Object Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How would I access a models attribute?

For example, the User model. Let's say I want to access the email portion of the User object.

It does not seem I am able to do

```
User.email
```

To access the email of the user.

I was wondering how I would access object attributes in the model and controller.

Comment: I am not sure if it is my syntax, or I am calling the attribute wrong. I try to check if User.email != 'example@example.com' I get a no method error.

Comment: You can access email attribute of an object of User model using `user=User.find(user_id)` and then `user.email` will retutn email of user with id 'user_id'

Comment: You are accessing the user class and not the user instance. You could do `user = User.first` and then `user.email`.
You must first learn some basics.

Comment: Thanks! So I would save the user_id to the variable 'user' and the call the attribute email on the user_id?

Comment: If I want to access the User.email in a different model. Would user=User.find(user_id) still work?

Answer (score 1):

To get email for all `User` records, you can do

```
User.pluck(:email)
```

If you want to get email a *particular user* object, you can do

```
User.find(1).email
```

Where `1` being the `id` of the *user* object in the `users` table.

I suggest you to read about [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object) query interface to understand better.

Comment: I was using 'User.email' as a general example. What if I wanted to check User.first_name or Post.title?

Comment: In the model, if I wanted the current User email, would I still do User.find(user_id).email?

Comment: @ApplesandOranges Yes You should fetch the current user first and then fetch the email for that user. You just cannot do `User.email` or `User.first_name`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Pavan User will refer to the model according to your comment. It would be better if you make it lowercase, I guess :)

Comment: @Sajin Yes you are right. Although OP said it as object, but actually doing as `User.email` where `User` being a model